# Use of 'the' after 'of'

Tags: grammaticality, plural-forms, parts-of-speech

What's the reason behind NOT using 'the' in these cases? I thought use of 'the' specifies the case about smth.

1) The number of THE CATS in my neighbourhood has increased.
(there is literally no hits with 'the cats' but only 'cats')

2) The number of THE survivors of the blast is mere 10.

Answer (score 1):

The cats and the survivors are not "specified" until they are numbered. That is why it is "the number", but not "the cats".

Consider another phrase: 
"A number of the alternatives are acceptable." In that sentence, all the alternatives are known specifically, and we can refer to a subset of them, so it's "the alternatives".

Comment: But if I say 'The number of THE survivors of ...' I'm specifying the survivors of a specific incident. Why is that wrong in any case?

Comment: Are you talking about the number or about the survivors? If you are talking specifically about the survivors, you can specify them as "the survivors". If you are talking about their number, it is "the number". There is no need to use two definite articles in a single phrase. Finally, the fact is that that is how it is done in English, as you have discovered with your own research. Rationalize it how you will.

Comment: You could say "A number of _the cats in my neighbourhood_  are overweight", or "A number of _the survivors of the blast_ are still in hospital". Here, _the_ identifies a group. In your examples, cats and survivors are just 'items' being counted.